# How to select only the data from a table where a variable includes rows for getdate() up to including the end of the week (Friday) inclusively

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: Data]

I have a table with items, stores and sales forecasts for each day of the week. Some days are missing. I want to sum the daily sales forecasts to get a weekly sales forecast but I only want to do this where today and everyday from today up to and including Friday is present in the table. Today could be any day of the week that this code is ran.

Expected result would be in the below format. Only the item/store combinations that had rows existing for everyday today up to and including Friday in the original table should be present here. The weekly forecast is a sum of all the days present (not just today until Friday).

Comment: I think sample data would really help.  Why doesn't a simply `group by` solve your problem?

Comment: It's not the sum and the group by that is the problem but filtering out item/stores that don't have all rows present according to the logic I described. I'll try to get the data.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Once you have given each row a week number, you simply need to count the number of daily forecasts as well as summing them. You then filter out those where there aren't 7 daily forecasts in a week.

Comment: Steve, It's not a full 7 days that I need it's any case where there are rows from today until Friday. So if it is Wednesday that would be 3 days required but if it is Monday that would be 5 days required. BTW I lack skills in asking the question and providing the data at the moment, working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a function that will give you the number of days until a specific weekday (@endDay). 
1=Sunday, 2=Monday.... 6=Friday, 7=Saturday. So for Friday you would pass the function 6 for @endDay. Here's the DDL to create the function:

```
-- Note that the logic above is assuming your @@DATEFIRST=7 (this is the default, you can check using `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`. 

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DaysUntilThisWeekday(@endDay TINYINT, @date DATE)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT N = ((@endDay+7)-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@date))%7
WHERE  @endDay BETWEEN 1 AND 7; -- startup predicate, no rows returned otherwise
GO
```

You could use the function against your table like this (including sample data that you can run locally):

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (SomeDate DATE);
INSERT @yourTable(SomeDate) VALUES ('20190518'),('20190519'),('20190520'),('20190521'),
          ('20190522'),('20190523'),('20190524'),('20190525'),('20190526'),('20190527')

DECLARE @endDay   TINYINT = 6, -- 6 for Friday
        @startDay DATE    = GETDATE();

SELECT     t.SomeDate
FROM       @yourTable                                 AS t
CROSS JOIN dbo.DaysUntilThisWeekday(@endDay,@startDay) AS f
WHERE      t.SomeDate BETWEEN @startDay AND DATEADD(DAY,f.N,@startDay);
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeDate
----------
2019-05-20
2019-05-21
2019-05-22
2019-05-23
2019-05-24
```

This is all the records between today and Friday (inclusive). If you can't create a function you could simply do this:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (SomeDate DATE);
INSERT @yourTable(SomeDate) VALUES ('20190518'),('20190519'),('20190520'),('20190521'),
          ('20190522'),('20190523'),('20190524'),('20190525'),('20190526'),('20190527')

DECLARE @startDay DATE = GETDATE();

SELECT t.SomeDate
FROM   @yourTable AS t
WHERE  t.SomeDate BETWEEN @startDay AND 
       DATEADD(DAY,((13)-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()))%7,@startDay);
```

Comment: This logic will work for the first part of the problem but then the final step is to SUM sales_forecast values for all days in the week for the item/stores that do meet the criteria (i.e. they do have rows for everyday from getdate() until the Friday). So to SUM all days values not just getdate() to Friday. I can probably figure out the last step but will want to do that the best way.